# fatal error C1027 while building Boost 1.49.0

Tags: c++, boost, build, bjam

I'm trying to build Boost 1.49.0 using MSVC2010 and it fails with the following error:

```
file bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\assoc_laguerre.obj.rsp
"libs\math\build\..\src\tr1\assoc_laguerre.cpp"
 -Fo"bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\assoc_laguerre.obj"
  -Yu"pch.hpp"
 -Fp"bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\pch.pch"
 -TP
 /O2
 /Ob2
 /W3
 /GR
 /MT
 /Zc:forScope
 /Zc:wchar_t
 /wd4675
 /EHs
 -c

-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1

-DBOOST_BUILD_PCH_ENABLED

-DNDEBUG

"-I."

"-Ilibs\math\src\tr1"

compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\assoc_laguerre.obj

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\assoc_laguerre.obj.rsp" 

assoc_laguerre.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1027: Inconsistent values for /Ym between creation and use of precompiled header
```

That is the first instance of that error, my log file has 995 instances of the same error before the build aborts.

The contents of project-config.jam are:

```
import option ; 

using msvc ; 

option.set keep-going : false ; 

using python : 3.2 : C:\\Tools\\Python\\3.2.2 ;
```

And the build command I used is:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage -q -d+2 -sICU_PATH="C:\Tools\ICU\4.8.1.1"
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: did you do anything other than the two simple commands: bootstrap / .\b2 ? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html section 5.2

Comment: @OrgnlDave I ran `bootstrap` followed by the `b2` command listed above (`b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage -q -d+2 -sICU_PATH="C:\Tools\ICU\4.8.1.1"`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368107/clxx-fatal-error-c1027-inconsistent-values-for-ym-between-creation-and-use-of-precompiled-headers) is an explanation of the error, and [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=60015&start=0) is someone who had this problem when building something else and his solution.

He modified his `/Zm` parameter from `/Zm1000` to `/Zm500` (you have `/Zm800`). I don't know if changing it to the same value will help you, but you can try playing with it (this compiler's flag explanation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c.aspx)).

You can use the `cxxflags` command line argument to modify the compiler flags (taken from [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html)).

Comment: Modifying the `/Zm` parameter didn't fix my problem but I'll accept this as the answer since the `cxxflags` argument led me the solution. I used `cxxflags="/Y- "` to ignore all precompiled headers.

Comment: I had the same issue in vc2012 and changing /Zm1000 down to /Zm100 made it work.

Comment: Strange fix with reducing /Zm but it fixed the error.